# Is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra bigger than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra without axiom of choice?

Tags: measure-theory

It is wellknown, that using the axiom of choice the Borel $\sigma$-algebra has cardinality $2^\mathbb{N}$, whereas the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra has cardinality $2^\mathbb{R}$. It immediately follows, that there are (many) Lebesgue-measurable sets, which are not Borel-measurable.

Now I know, that the existence of avmeasure on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is consistent with ZF. Though this really doesn't say anything about the Borel algebra in the absence of choice it lead me to the question if $Bor_\mathbb{R}=Leb_\mathbb{R}$, where the first is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all intervals and the second are the measurable sets of the (outer) Lebesgue measure.

Are there any sources on this?

Comment: Without the Axiom of Choice, you can prove that the Cantor set is an uncountable Borel subset of $ [0,1] $ with Borel measure $ 0 $. Any subset of the Cantor set is thus Lebesgue-measurable, and we know that there are $ 2^{\mathbb{R}} $-many of these.

Comment: Yes, but can you prove without Choice, that the Borel-algebra has cardinality $2^\mathbb{N}$? The proof I know uses transfinite induction on the Borel hierarchy and I think the latter one need choice.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32720/non-borel-sets-without-axiom-of-choice looks to be somewhat relevant here...

Comment: It's the same as asking if you can prove the existence of a non-Borel subset of $\mathbb R$ without AC; if you have a non-Borel subset of $\mathbb R$ then you can get a non-Borel subset of the Cantor set, and that will have measure zero.

Comment: However, I believe I've heard tell that $\mathbb R$ can be a countable union of countable sets. In that case, every set of real numbers is a countable union of countable sets, and therefore a Borel set.

Comment: Yes, that is also the answer in Stevens Link. Thank you for this.

Comment: Probably the question makes more sense if you assume some weak form of AC, so that countable unions of countable sets are countable.

Comment: The answers in Steven's link seem to imply, that already countable choice forces the existence of non-Borel sets, so i think one has to be very carefull to add axioms. Maybe one can really just add the axiom that countable unions of countable sets are countable, but then again I have no Idea how to proceed.

Comment: @Takirion I was going to say that that axiom is equivalent to ACC, but that looks incorrect. You might have a look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74743/countable-unions-and-the-axiom-of-countable-choice too, which has a number of references to specific resources, models of 'unions of countables are countable', etc.

Comment: @Takirion: In the Feferman-Lévy model, every subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ is Borel-measurable (as $ \mathbb{R} $ is a countable union of countable sets) and Lebesgue-measurable (as every subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ has null Borel measure). If there were a proof in $ \mathsf{ZF} $ alone of the assertion that the Lebesgue $ \sigma $-algebra $ \mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}) $ has a larger cardinality than the Borel $ \sigma $-algebra $ \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}) $, then the assertion would be true in the Feferman-Lévy model, which clearly contradicts the previous statement.

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore If (="in models where") $\mathbb{R}$ is the countable union of countable sets, does this imply, that there is no measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mu([a,b])=b-a$?

Comment: @Takirion: There is no such measure. Any measure in such a model would have to be the trivial measure as a countable subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ has null measure (as can be seen from its outer measure).

Comment: @Takirion: The moment you assume $ \mathsf{AC}_{\omega} $, it is no longer true that $ \mathbb{R} $ is a countable union of countable sets (because $ \mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{AC}_{\omega} $ says that a countable union of countable sets is countable, while $ \mathsf{ZF} $ says that $ \mathbb{R} $ is uncountable), so measure theory becomes non-trivial.

Comment: @Takirion: As for your original question, in order to prove that $ |\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})| = |\mathbb{R}| $, we need a version of $ \mathsf{AC} $ at least as strong as $ \mathsf{AC}_{\omega} $ that gives us $ |\omega_{1} \times \mathbb{R}| = |\mathbb{R}| $ (because the Borel hierarchy is defined by transfinite induction up to $ \omega_{1} $). I think that $ \mathsf{AC}_{\omega_{1}} $ does the trick, but I could be wrong.